# Is PhoneGap still required to put Sencha Touch 2 app in the app store?

Tags: cordova, app-store, sencha-touch-2

I'm new to using Sencha Touch, and one thing is confusing me.  I started by creating a basic app by using Sencha command 4.0.4.84.  I did not do anything to add in PhoneGap.  I got the thing built, and even got it onto an actual Android phone by using `sencha app build native`, then using adb to push it onto the phone.  The app works on the phone without PhoneGap.

However, I've seen people saying something about how PhoneGap is required if you want to put a Sencha Touch app in the various app stores.  I cannot tell if this information is out of date (since I know for Sencha Touch 1, you had to use PhoneGap to package Sencha Touch natively), or if there is some limitation with Sencha Touch 2's native build that prevents you from publishing in the app store, but you can download to the phone manually, at least for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap is still required to create an native app.
Sencha Cmd hides it from you. Under the hood it will create a phonegap project and configure it accordingly.

Nevertheless I would recommend to understand phonegap as its the basic technology your are working with.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes so much more sense.  I'm finding it difficult to find very basic information like this.  It's much easier to find API documentation.